# Add field collection table in code

Tags: forms

I am creating a form to collect data for a specific content type which has a field collection in it.

So basically I am creating nodes manually through form API. 
What I need to do is to add a field collection table to my form which corresponds to the field collection I declared in the node type.

I have got how the table is rendered in the original add content form, which is like this:

```
[field_student_grades] => Array
    (
        [#type] => container
        [#attributes] => Array
            (
                [class] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => field-type-field-collection
                        [1] => field-name-field-student-grades
                        [2] => field-widget-field-collection-table
                    )

            )

        [#weight] => 5
        [#tree] => 1
        [#language] => und
        [und] => Array
            (
                [0] => Array
                    (
                        [#entity_type] => field_collection_item
                        [#entity] => FieldCollectionItemEntity Object
                            (
                                [fieldInfo:protected] => 
                                [hostEntity:protected] => stdClass Object
                                    (
                                        [uid] => 1
```

But I do not know how to deal with the [und] and [hostEntity:protected] and stdClass Object in code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't access Protected members directly.

you'll need to extend the class that represents that object to provide getter methods for the protected properties.